# CSS line-image-line that's less than 100% wide, and still responsive?

Tags: html, css, frontend

How do I replicate something like this with HTML/CSS?

[image: sample image]

Where:

1. I can have an icon or small image in the center.
2. Is responsive, and functions with my current breakpoints.
3. *(fixed - width 80%, margin: 0 auto)* The line isn't 100% width across the screen.

I found a few examples on stack overflow, but they don't seem to fit my purpose exactly.

Unfortunately this sample ([found here](https://themeforest.net/item/david-mary-event-wedding-template/7441572)) is exactly what I want to do, but it's picture, so I can't view the source beneath it.

I've got the below code, however as you can see it has 2 problems.

```
<div style="height: 1px; background-color: grey; text-align: center;">

<span style="position: relative; top: -2.25em; padding: 5px;"> 
<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Alpha_transparency_image.png' alt="text" style="width:80px;height:80px;"></span>

</div>
```

[image]
(See also [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyoyjk7k/1/))

---

1) Transparency on the image makes the line goes 'through' it. Is there any way I can control this?

2) *(fixed - width 80%, margin: 0 auto)* The line is 100% width end to end

Thanks !

Edit: Fixed the width issue with  (width 80%, margin: 0 auto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im a little bit in a rush, try this out though, ill fix the centering when I get home

CSS

```
.clearfix:after {visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }


.container{
  width:70%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.left{
  margin:3% auto;
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

img{
  margin:0;
  width:20%;
  float:left;


}

.right{
  margin:3% 0;
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Alpha_transparency_image.png'>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work ! Are we basically creating a container of 'left+img+right' size, and setting that to transparent (i.e. visibility: hidden)?

Comment: (As you mentioned) for anyone else seeing this in the future, it doesn't Center exactly. I'll play around and see where I can do.

Comment: just got home! glad to see you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Try this and assign same `background-color` to your `icon .fa fa-heart-o` as your main i.e parent div consist of. Thus this merge your `background-color` with your `icon background-color`.

```css
body{
  background:#111;
}
#line{
  width:100%;
  height:2px;
  background:#fff;
}
#line > .fa{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:45%;
  color:#f22;
  background:#111;
  width:50px;
  padding-left:40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="line">
<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
</div>
```

If you are planning to add that icon above image then use pseudo `::before` and `::after` selector to your parent div to create left and right border and `background:transparent` to you icon. Aligning of element you need to adjust, but this are the 2 ways to align icon in center and background transparent.

```css
body{
  background:url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
}
#line{
  width:100%;
  height:2px;
}
#line::before{
  content:'';
  width:45%;
  height:2px;
  background:#f22;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
#line::after{
  content:'';
  width:45%;
  height:2px;
  background:#f22;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
#line > .fa{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:42%;
  color:#f22;
  background:transparent;
  width:50px;
  padding-left:40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="line">
<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: That works for this, but I want to use it in a few spots.. I'm thinking of one particular instance where the background is an image, and a solid colour would look out of place.. I could work around that, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: @mbka work with pseudo selector to create line before and after the icon.